# Are a particle's decay products' kinetic energies known?

Tags: particle-physics

In physics textbooks, when particle decays are described, it shows what particles a certain particle decays into but not their kinetic energies. Sometimes the rest masses of the product particles are only about half of the rest mass of the parent particle. Seldom is it close to 100%. Does all that missing energy go into kinetic energy of the product particles or are gamma rays produced that aren't mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

> In physics textbooks, when particle decays are described, it shows what particles a certain particle decays into but not their kinetic energies.

For two body decays, the kinetmatics is simple. Energy and momentum conservation can be used and the result is known. It is not mentioned in the textbooks because the result is trivial in the center of mass system of the decaying particle, look at the [examples here](https://indico.cern.ch/event/391122/contributions/928962/attachments/782786/1073126/twoBodyDecay.pdf) .:

Once a third particle enters, the individual energy spectra cannot be determined kinematically and from energy momentum conservation any longer. A good example is the discovery of the neutrino, because beta decay has variable spectra for proton and electron, [a third particle had to be proposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino#Pauli's_proposal) to get energy and momentum conservation.

In general, in particle interactions, energy and momentum conservation rules and in decays, extra particles will have to be assumed so that the laws hold.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, energy and momentum are conserved in decays, which means some of the mass energy of the parent particle needs to become kinetic energy. In 1 to 2 decays, the exact energy and momentum of the child particles is determined by just energy and momentum conservation. In other collisions, for instance 2 to 2, there is some randomness in the energy splitting, but everything will still conserve energy.